# Laravel: Call to undefined method orderBy

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, declaration, laravel-5

I want to sort my list through descending order using "orderBy" in Laravel.

Im getting an error saying: Call to undefined method orderBy.

**Here's my controller**

```
 $sections = Section1::all()->orderBy('name', 'DESC')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `Section1::all()` you get the results as an object so you can't chain query builders such as `orderBy`. What you are looking for is:

```
 $sections = Section1::orderBy('name', 'DESC')->get();
```

Which says build a query for the Sections1 model ordered by name descending and get the results.

You can't use `all()` and `get()` together.

Comment: oooooohhhh  I see :D  Thanks for the tip :3  and the Code works!! Thank you!!! :3